# Extracting the value of a variant to a superclass

Tags: c++, types, variant

Consider the following classes

```
class A {
    public:
    virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    std::string to_string(){
        return "B";
    }
};

class C : public A {
    public:
    std::string to_string(){
        return "C";
    }
};
 
class D {};
```

Now I will have a variant `std::variant<B*, C*, D*> bcd;`The variable can of course, depending on the user input, hold either a variable of type `B*` or of type `C*`. At a given time in the program, I want to extract the value to pass to a method taking the superclass `A*` as an argument. Now, if I do this explicitly like this:

```
bc = new C();
A* a = std::get<C*>(bc);
```

It works as expected. But I do not know at this point, which type the inner value of `bc` will have.

I have tried the following:

- Adding `A*` to the variant and trying to access it with `std::get<A*>(bc)`, which results in a bad variant access.
- Creating a visitor pattern to return the type (even though this seems cumbersome for this simple task) like this

  ```
  class Visitor {
    template<typename TType>
    TType operator()(TType arg) {
      return arg;
    }
  };
  A* a2 = std::visit(visitor, bc);
  ```

  which produces a `no type named ‘type’ in ‘std::conditional_t‘`. (I also tried it without templates).

Is there a right / elegant way to do this without having to do something like

```
 if(B* b = std::get_if<B*>(bc))
```

for every type that I have?

Comment: You seem to have an XY-problem: why are you doing this way? If you already have a common base and already need to use pointers, `variant<B*, C*>` doesn't really have much benefit over simply `A*`. We use variants exactly when we try to avoid an arbitrary base class and using pointers.

Comment: @Iorro I agree that this is true in my example. In my actual program, the variant contains multiple types and can have a lot of different values, which do not share the same base. In most cases, I know exactly which type the variant will hold, but not no this one. Also, at some point I want to pass the value to a function taking the subclass as an argument, which is not possible with superclasses if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with `std::visit`, not sure what the error is exactly but I would recommend using a lambda instead of a custom struct:

```
int main(){
    std::variant<B*, C*> bc;
    bc = new C();
    A* a = std::visit([](auto&& e)->A*{return e;},bc);
    a->to_string();
}
```

The above will compile iff all variants can be casted to `A*` and is thus safe.

If some of variants are not derived from `A*`, you could use this longer version:

```
    A* a = std::visit(
        [](auto& e) -> A* {
            if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<decltype(e),A*>)
                return e;
            else
                return nullptr;
        },
        bc);
```

It will return `nullptr` if the currently held type cannot be casted to `A`.

One can hide the ugly lambda (the simple one above can be hidden too) into a global variable template, full example:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto shared_cast = [](auto& e) -> T* {
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<decltype(e), T*>)
        return e;
    else
        return nullptr;
};

int main() {
    std::variant<B*, C*, D*> bc;
    bc = new C();
    A* a = std::visit(shared_cast<A>, bc);

    if (a != nullptr) a->to_string();
}
```

Feel free to refactor the whole `std::visit` expression into a template function:

```
template <typename T,typename V>
T* visit2(V& variant){
    return std::visit(shared_cast<T>,variant);
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, in my actual Program, not all variants are derived from the same superclass (I edited my question accordingly), so this does not compile unfortunaly. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: @wittn Yes, I edited my answer, but it is less pretty now, hence the last example.